# How can I pass data to libcore on Android?

Tags: android, android-source

I was modifying the libcore on Andorid for debugging purpose.
It took a lot of time to build even for a variable change.

Is it possible to pass the data to libcore of android?
(so I can change the data in the running time).

I tried `System.getProperty()` but the data could not cross process.
 
I also tried SystemProperties.get() but it seems it can not be used in libcore (it could not find the package and symbol).

Does anyone know how to pass data to the libcore on Android?

Comment: on one hand - I would have try and figured out if there is a JNI public method that I can call. If so you can create a "native" method in your java code as a bridge method and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks Nativ. JNI is doable but a little complicated for me. Finally, I used a file to pass data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nativ.
JNI is doable but a little complicated for me.

Finally, I used a simple, easy but stupid way to do that.
I created a file and saved my parameter in this file, and get the data from libcore.

It is a stupid way but worked for me for debugging.
Now I don't need to rebuild libcore and It saved much for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection on class android.os.SystemProperties to get System Properties at runtime.
Code example:

```
public static String getSystemProperty(String key) {
    String value = "";
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        if (clazz != null) {
            Object object = clazz.newInstance();
            value = (String) (clazz.getMethod("get", String.class).invoke(object, key));
        } else {
            System.err.println(TAG + ", getSystemProperty: Class is null.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}
```